# Heroku Rails build failing due to Bootsnap and Rake issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to follow along with the [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org) and can't seem to get builds working on Heroku.

My build log is here:
https://pastebin.com/pBnGkBXe

Here are the errors I've tried debugging so far:

```
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
```

Running `bundle exec rake -P` locally **does** work on my repository.

```
 !     /tmp/build_5f6ec788/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)
 !     from /tmp/build_5f6ec788/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 !     from /tmp/build_5f6ec788/bin/rake:3:in `require_relative'
 !     from /tmp/build_5f6ec788/bin/rake:3:in `<main>'
```

I wasn't able to figure out what was happening here.

I tried running this with both the [Rails Default Gemfile](https://pastebin.com/3KHNiRTU) and the [Rails Tutorial Gemfile](https://pastebin.com/aDECPxJK) and it resulted in the same Bootsnap error.

Can anyone make suggestions on how to get this Heroku deployment working?

Thank you!

Comment: having this same issue after upgrading to Rail 6 and I'm on ruby 2.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

I was running Ruby v2.6.3. Upgrade to 2.7.2 and fixing that in the Gemfile resulted in a successful deploy to Heroku.